# Units of a dirac delta function in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, dimensional-analysis, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

In quantum mechanics the eigenfunctions of the position are dirac delta functions, $A\delta(x-x_0)$, where $A$ is some constant. Eigenfunctions of the position are usually normalized with a "Delta function normalization". This means that $\langle x | x' \rangle = \delta(x-x')$, which can be understood in a formal way if one applies the shifting property of one of the delta functions to the other in the integral $$ \langle x | x' \rangle = \int_\mathbb{R}\mid A \mid^2\delta(y-x)\delta(y-x')~\mathrm{d}y.$$

This gives as a result $\mid A \mid^2 \delta(x-x')$, so the coefficient $A$ should be set to $1$. Up until today I thought I understood this kind of fine, but I realized now that there is a problem with dimensions somewhere here. In order for an expression like $ \int_\mathbb{R} \psi^*(x) \psi(x)~\mathrm{d}x$ to be dimensionless, position space wavefunctions should have dimensions of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$. This means that an expansion in terms of position eigenfunctions, like $$ \mid \psi \rangle =  \int_\mathbb{R} \psi(x) \mid x \rangle~\mathrm{d} x$$ would only make sense if position eigenfunctions themselves had units of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$.

This is a bit disturbing to me, the inner product of two position eigenfunctions should, if one looks at the integral, 
$$\langle x | x' \rangle = \int_\mathbb{R}\delta(y-x)\delta(y-x')~\mathrm{d}y$$ be dimensionless (two things with dimensions $\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$ inside and de $\mathrm{d}x$ factor, with dimensions $\frac{1}{L}$) but delta function normalization implies it is a new delta function... thus it has dimensions of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$! **How can this be made right?**

It is also strange to me that in other areas of physics (electromagnetism for instance) delta functions are usually given dimensions of $\frac{1}{D}$, where $D$ is the dimension of the argument. This seems not to be the case here, and I'm a bit weirded out by it. When changing from cartesian to polar coordinates, for instance, the natural thing in electromagnetism is to consider $$\delta(x-x_0) \delta(y-y_0) = \frac{\delta(r-r_0)\delta(\phi-\phi_0)}{r},$$ but this messes up units in quantum mechanics, because in quantum mechanics the left hand side would have different dimensions than the right hand side... One could perhaps consider $$\frac{\delta(r-r_0)\delta(\phi-\phi_0)}{\sqrt{r}}$$ as the right thing to write down in QM, but there should be only one way to write delta functions in different variables... shouldn't there? the Jacobian determinant should go downstairs. **How does this make sense in QM?**

Comment: Related, possible duplicate : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33760/

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89958/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the inner product of two position eigenfunctions shouldn't be dimensionless. You chose to normalize them such that $\langle x | x' \rangle = \delta(x-x')$; therefore, the inner product has the dimensions of $\delta$, i.e., $1/L$. Don't confuse the state with the wavefunction: the wavefunction corresponding to $|a\rangle$, $\delta(x-a)$ is not $|a\rangle$ but $\langle x | a \rangle$, so it has a different dimension.