# Dimensions of Delta Function

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, dirac-delta-distributions

What is the **dimensions** of *Dirac Delta Function* and **why is it so** ?

Comment: Hint: if $f(x)=\int g(y)h(x,\,y)d^ny$ then $[h]=\frac{[f]}{[g]\prod_{i=1}^n[y_i]}$. Now take $g(y)=f(y),\,h(x,\,y)=\delta(x-y)$.

Comment: Voting to close as a math question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33760/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the units or dimensions of the Dirac delta function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33760/)

Answer (score 3):

$$1 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x-x_0) dx$$
Since the product $\delta(x-x_0) dx$ is adimentional, the dimension of $\delta$ must be the inverse of the dimension of $x$.