# The dimension analysis for the langevin force

Tags: dimensional-analysis, drag, brownian-motion

In wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation), the langevin force formula is given as
$$\langle\eta_i(t)\,\eta_j(t')\rangle = {2\gamma\,k_B\,T\,\delta_{i,j}\,\delta(t-t')}.$$
However, $\gamma$ has a dimension of $\rm M\,T^{-1}$, and $k_B\,T$ has a dimension of $\rm L^2\,T^{-2}\, M$.
In conclusion, $\langle\eta_i(t)\,\eta_j(t')\rangle$ will have a $\rm L^2\,T^{-3}\,M^2$. 
However, the square of force has a dimension of $\rm L^2\,T^{-4}\,M^2$.
So dimension of time ($\rm T$) is different. I can't understand this. Could you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the units or dimensions of the Dirac delta function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33760/37364)

Comment: @mmesser314 OMG. Yes! it really helped a lot! Thank you for answering